# No constructor defined error biztalk server

Tags: .net, biztalk, class-library, biztalk2006r2

I am creating a pipeline component using .net class library 
Where I want to pass an HTML document as a input and get a XMLdocument as output,

I am getting an error in this line

```
HtmlDocument OrgDoc= new HtmlDocument
```

The error is no constructor for HTML document do I miss some reference if yes what it that. Actually I am using system.windows.forms.htmldocument.

Any suggestions to rectify the error is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BizTalk is correct; `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument` has no public constructors. It is intended to be used via the `WebBrowser` control *only* (to represent the DOM), and I don't recommend trying to do that on a server. If you are trying to parse HTML, try using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: In my biztalk Application i did configured my receive location as file so biztalk server itself takes the html for the processing........ Now the problem is to create a pipeline component to convert HTML to XML

Comment: @Mark Gravell: I included the html agility pack to my application as a reference i hope this will work for me